AND Gate from LEDs to drive another LED
To preface... I'm a little rusty having focused on mostly ECAD the last several years.
I'm in a new job and I'm working on a test rig for some boards. When the boards are running they have a static high signal that I have connected to LEDs and I have 8 of these to indicate a board is running a test. When a test fails the signal goes low and subsequently the LED turns off.
My boss wants me to have a 9th RED LED that lights up to indicate at least one of them has failed.
I am looking at using CD4068BE IC to T them off to an AND gate but testing it the LEDs don't light up and when a test fails (because I make it fail on purpose to check) the RED LED doesn't light up. Do I need to add a buffer between the T and the AND gate? Since the CD4068BE IC can only do 6.8mA how can I have it drive the RED LED?
Thank you for any help.

Draw a schematic how exactly the 8 leds are connected/driven.

Signal voltages, currents, etc???  If an external circuit is required, what voltages are available to power it?

When the test is over, does the 9th LED have to latch and hold the result?

Aside from the other good comments, have you looked at the 7415? It's got (3) 3-in AND gates with open collector outputs that can sink enough current for an LED and can be wire-OR'd for that purpose. Just a thought.

@Colin I think in his particular case we are talking about inverted logic. 1 becomes 0, 0 becomes 1 and AND becomes OR. Feeding 8 1s into an AND gate has exactly the same logic as feeding 8 0s into an OR gate except the output signal is inverted.

indicate at least one of them has failed.  ... please edit your post to clarify what them is

I'll echo AnalogKid's comment, asking for voltages. Without knowing what supply voltage you have available, and what the individual output signal voltages are, any answer is going to be a shot in the dark. A typical LED these days is going to be ridiculously bright at 6.8mA, so that's more than enough current for a single LED. Are they just regular LEDs, or are they hybrid 12V modules claiming to be LEDs? I have to ask how you wired it up and still got it to fail, so please provide a schematic of your existing (and failing) setup.

If I assume you've added series resistors to the existing LEDs that are high enough that the logic levels at the output are still valid (this is an important caveat!) like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
.. then the 4068 should work if properly connected. Valid CMOS logic levels are 1.5V for low and 3.5V for high, and you should be more like 1V and 4V respectively for reliability.
If you resistor is too low (or if it is missing!) then your 'high' level may not reach a valid '1' and the AND gate will show a failure even if the LEDs are all 'on'.
The 4068 indeed does have a wimpy output current, particularly at 5V.
If you want to buffer the 8 output and the 9th as well, you could use a couple ULN2003A Darlington arrays, each will buffer  7  lines. You must have a series resistor for the LEDs.

simulate this circuit
"COM" can be connected to +5 or left open. If you ground COM the LEDs will all turn on (perhaps useful as an LED test).

ULN2803 has 8 inputs (and he wants 8 inputs),  connect "COM" to 100K into a darlington transistor base to drive the error LED

@JasenСлаваУкраїні Yes, that's another way. The 2803 is double the cost though and the darlington is another part to buy.

The question is missing some critical details, so this is very much guesswork.
Here is a first pass schematic for what I'm guessing is the question.  This uses the AND gate suggested by the TS.  Inputs 2 through 7 are removed for clarity.
Without his schematic, we do not know how he has things wired.  Based on his description, I'm guessing that the input LEDs are connected to GND, with their current-limiting resistors connected to the input signals.  In this case, the inputs to the AND gate never go above 2.1 V (-ish), the high end of the Vf range for a standard small LED.  If this is the problem, reversing the LEDs and resistors is a solution.
Cheap green LEDs have a Vf of around 2 V.  IF the external system is driving the LED outputs with 12 V signals, then the AND inputs will be around 10 V when high, plenty of margin above the nominal 6 V input transition level.
Even at 12 V, a standard CD4xxx gate output cannot source much current.  And, it's a bad idea to run any logic gate (especially CMOS) at its max rated output current.  Adding Q1 allows for plenty of current for the error LED (D9).


8 input NAND with negative logic is required for more choices.
There are 6 mA,  20 mA CMOS options and 50 mA TTL level using 74ACT11030N  where any fault-in must* be <1V with output to Anode at 5V for a fault and a current limiting series R as your choice.
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/74act11030.pdf?ts=1723004093081

0.8V max low is guaranteed but the threshold is near 1.3V.


Note that the recommended max output current is 24 mA, not 50 mA.

@AnalogKid you understand that is for only if you need rated Voh Vol which is irrelevant to act as a LED driver. There is absolutely no need to use more than 24 mA unless you want to and you can up to 50mA abs. Max

I don't recommend operating any electronic component at its "absolute maximum" ratings.  Such a design would fail even the most basic design review.

I wasn't recommending it, but it can tolerate up to this limit both thermally and wire bond safety.
